# Getting Error "CS1026: ) expected" when trying to combing .js files using SquishIt

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, squishit

I'm trying to combine a couple of javascript files using the [SquishIt](http://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt) library. I'm following the steps that are provided [here](http://www.codethinked.com/post/2010/05/26/SquishIt-The-Friendly-ASPNET-JavaScript-and-CSS-Squisher.aspx) but I'm getting a compilation error stating " CS1026: ) expected" when I try to load the page. The application is an ASP.NET MVC2 app.

The code for the SquishIt functionality is:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="SquishIt.Framework" %>
```

and in the body of my html:

```
<%= Bundle.JavaScript()
    .Add("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.js")
    .Add("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.2.js")
    .ForceRelease()
    .Render("~/Scripts/combined_#.js");
%>
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use <%= with a ; so you need to do:

```
<%= Bundle.JavaScript()... .Render("..") %>
```

Or

```
<% Bundle.JavaScript() .. .Render(".."); %>
```

So it depends on what Render does, if it returns a string, you have to use the <%= %> syntax, but if it does the rendering, then you have to use a semi-colon.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. So used to ending every statement with a semi-colon that I didn't even notice that I'd done it.

Comment: I know I do it all the time :-)